# trying to find source of Google Fonts in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, google-fonts

I am running a wordpress website. Since I am in operating/hosting the EU, I just got sued using google fonts and I was like: "wtf?" Because I do not use google fonts ... after Inspecting my website I found that actually something in my config is loading Roboto.

The theme is 'Kalium' from Laborator. Wordpress WordPress 6.0.3. Everything up to date.
[image: this is where it is loaded in the html.]

I already deactivated all 'unnecessary' plugins and looked though my custom CSS. The import is nowhere to be found. On another website, I use the same theme and also minimal/basic plugins and do NOT have the same problem.

so my question is: **How do I find where to deactivate/delete this? How do I find the source?**
Is there a best practice to go about sth. like this?

Comment: If you have all the files (WP Core, themes, etc.) on your local machine, search for `googleapis` in all the files. You'll most likely find it. My first guess would have been the theme, however, since you said you've used the theme before without the font loading, that rules the theme (potentially) out.

Comment: How the F can you get sued over using GFont ?

Comment: @amarinediary it looks like, in Germany, per GDPR, Google Fonts violates "Privacy and Security" - https://blog.runcloud.io/google-fonts-gdpr/ - wild. Also, OP, that article has some good advice (if you need it)

Comment: @disinfor This is insane. The ramifications of that ruling are crazy ! Literally all CDN's can be put on noticed for that.

Comment: Does the theme have Typography settings in its Customize menu? Maybe you (or somebody) chose a particular font on this site. Plus, it's a commercial product. Contact their support team. (I would jump fast if a customer of mine was sued for using a product of mine. I bet they will too.)

Comment: @O.jones The Theme has such option. I have no google fonts activated there.

Comment: @amarinediary The problem is with the loading-order of any Site. If I load the fonts after consent, everything is fine.

Comment: @disinfor I will search for that.